# How to bypass the email authentication in Git-Lab version control for user creation

Tags: git, gitlab

I have setup the Git-Lab version control in our premises, I wanted to create bulk user by bypassing the email authentication of each user.

I have created the users from administrator account, but user is not able access from web panel because it saying email verification is pending.

I don't want create email setup on server.

Is there any workaround for not using email?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Gitlab version **8.10.5** there is no need existing email id/ server to create the user. 
In Sign-Up option you can create the user and access it.

Comment: Thanks its done ..i had installed the newer version on GitLab and its working.